# Create invoice number in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a data like this :

```
idOrder |  transactionDate    
   31   | 04/06/2014 7:58:38  
   32   | 05/06/2014 8:00:08  
   33   | 05/06/2014 14:23:51
```

I want build stored procedure that produce invoice number automatically, e.g. :

In 4 June, there are 1 invoice number : 201406041 (20140604 from date and 1 at last from total order happened that day).

So, in 5 June, there are 2 invoice number : 201406051 and 201406052

I am lack on SQL scripting except this query to count transaction per day:

```
SELECT 
   count(idOrder) as total 
FROM 
   TR_Order 
GROUP BY 
   Convert(char(8), transactionDate, 111);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WARNING:** any such approach using `COUNT()` or `MAX()` is **NOT SAFE** under load! If you have a busy system, you **WILL** have duplicates sooner or later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from test  

select 
    idorder, transactiondate,  
    REPLACE(CAST(transactionDate as DATE),'-','') + 
            CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(transactionDate AS DATE) 
                                   ORDER BY idorder) AS varchar(8)) AS InvoiceNumber  
from test
```

[image]

Comment: This is true but that query is sick. Thanks master!

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(VARCHAR(8), transactionDate, 112) 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), RANK() 
        over (partition by convert(date, transactionDate) order by idorder))
    as 'invoice no'
    , * 
from TR_Order
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this may help you to generate invoice number by using system-date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INVOICE(IN INPUT VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8)

RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

DECLARE TG VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE TH VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE TI VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE TJ VARCHAR(255);

SET TG = ((SELECT count(idOrder) as total FROM TR_Order GROUP BY Convert(char(8), transactionDate, 111) + 1);

SET TH = SUBSTRING(curdate(),1,4);

SET TI = SUBSTRING(curdate(),6,2);

SET TJ = SUBSTRING(curdate(),9,2);

SET INPUT = CONCAT(TH,TI,TJ,TG);

RETURN INPUT;

END;
```

Comment: This is **not** valid for (Microsoft) **SQL Server** !